# Meaning of "call it" in The Avengers

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns

I have been studying English by reading The Avengers script.
Here are two passages.

1. > *The Avengers look up, watching as more Leviathans and hundreds of warriors fly through the portal.*
   >   — Natasha: G... Guys?
   >   — Stark: Call it, Captain.
   >   — Captain: All right, listen up. [blah blah]

   Seeing that Captain starts ordering each of them, does *call it* mean "order it"? In any case I don't see what "it" means here. Could you explain this to me?
2. > — Fury: Agent Coulson is down.
   >   — Other: A medical team is on its way to your location.
   >   — Fury: They're here. They called it.
   >   — All: ...

   When Fury says "they called it", I guess it maybe means "they said he is dead already". *Call* = "say", *it* = "death"? Did I understand right?

   Also, can *down* mean "dead"? When my father passed away, can I say "my father was down" instead?

Answer (score 8):

The first instance represents a shortened form of "**call the play**".  This term derives from American Football where it refers to when a team is told what they're going to (attempt to) do after the next restart - the person who decides this is usually either the coach or the quarterback.  Colloquially, it can refer to taking ownership of a decision and making it. In the context, "**it**" is "**the play**", ie the strategy that the Avengers will use to deal with the situation.

Your interpretation of the second instance is correct - it derives from the formal requirement of medical professionals to make a note of the time of death for patients they've been treating - more fully: "**they've called the time of death**".

As per msam's answer, "**down**" doesn't necessarily mean **dead**, it could just mean "**out of operation**", it's commonly applied to people who have been shot and are incapacitated.

Comment: Good answer for the first scene, but the second one comes from medical jargon, calling a code or time of death.

Comment: Yes, I can see that now that you point it out

Answer (score 7):

1. On of the meanings of making the call means deciding between various possibilities, usually after being presented with some incomplete data, and since he's the commander "making a decision" = "giving orders".
2. Another related instance where this meaning is used is when a patient dies and the doctor has to write the time of death - in this case the doctors calls it, meaning he is declaring the patient dead.
3. "Down" does not necessarily mean dead, it just means in a lower state. Someone can be downed/ knocked down/brought down with a punch (he could be dead but that is irrelevant). So no, you cannot say your father is down.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of idiomatic phrases involving "calling" something, which means to make a declaration. The phrase that springs to my mind is "*call it a day*", which means to declare that something is over or should finish. There is also the similar phrase "*call time on [something]*" which also means to declare that something specific should now end.

In your examples, asking someone to "call it" is a recommendation that something should finish. It also implies that the one being asked has the responsibility or the authority to make that call.